# Can I make my Google Chrome extension open source?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, licensing

I'm developing a **Google Chrome extension** and I'm going to deploy it in the store soon.

I also want to host the code on my website, as I usually do with any source code I write. I've read Google's terms of agreement, but I didn't really figure out **if** I'm allowed to do this. *(I find the TOS very complicated to read and understand.)*

## Question

Can I release the full source code of my Google Chrome Extension under the [Simplified BSD license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses#2-clause_license_.28.22Simplified_BSD_License.22_or_.22FreeBSD_License.22.29)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing / Terms of Use / legal issues, not programming or software development. See the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find anything in the Chrome web policy that indicates you can't do that. Since everyone can open the Inspector and see the resources for every chrome extension or see the source files of your extension through their installed local path. Actually Chrome web store review team hopes every item in the web store should have clear and readable code that they will look through all the functionalities of the item and set the items in pending review or take them down if any of them are obscure or may be harmful to users.

However, even though anyone can review your source code. Nobody has the right to reuse, change and/or distribute your code without your explicit permission. If you or anyone found something in the Chrome Web Store that violates the copyright, they can always [Report Abuse](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/1078344?hl=en) under Details tab in the web store.